# Hard drive partition cannot be removed

Tags: bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I tried to install windows with bootcamp assistant but an error occurred and the installation failed (I don't remember the error message). Bootcamp assistant then tried to remove the partition it created but it was taking too long (over an hour) so I closed the program and restarted it. Now I can't click continue as this error shows up.

[image: bootcamp assistant error]

I tried to remove the partition using disk utility but the minus button is greyed out.

[image: Minus button greyed out in disk utility]

I am new to macOS and have no idea what to do. My goal is to remove that partition and and install windows. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Problems like this are best handled by enter commands in a Terminal application window. The exact commands could be posted to an answer if you can add the output from the command `diskutil list` to your question. This command will not change your Mac. The command just prints a text description of the pie chart you posted.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

1) backup your data - but you already did that didn't you..

2) Wipe and partition the drive from scratch and install macOS and windows from the start

Hopefully you will have a clean fresh install for both.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to do that? I have no idea what I am doing. Thanks.

Comment: so backup : https://support.apple.com/mac-backup, install mac os : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904, then bootcamp : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468